# What options are needed to compile ATL programs using the MSVC 2010 command line tools?

Tags: visual-c++, atl

I'm trying to build an ATL program using the MS command line tools from the Windows SDK 7.1. I've installed the Windows Driver Kit 7.1.0 in order to get the ATL headers and libraries and for the most part I've been successful. I can build it perfectly for x86 systems using either MSBuild or a custom makefile for nmake but when I try and build it for x64 I get the following errors:

```
<project>\include\atl71\atlplus.h(21): error C3360: 'ATL4': cannot create IAttributeHandler [<project>.vcxproj]
<project>\include\atl71\atlplus.h(21): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation [<project.vcxproj]
  0 Warning(s)
  2 Error(s)
```

The really annoying thing is that using the exact same solution file and configuration, Visual Studio can build the x64 version fine. Clearly I'm missing something as all these tools use the same version of cl.exe to perform the actual compilation...

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Express? The only reason to justify use of 13 years old version of ATL.

Comment: I'm trying not to use Visual Studio at all...

I'm using ATL 7 however because the code was written using Visual Studio .Net 2003 and I want to get it building as is before I think about updating it

Comment: The best would be to use ATL installed with Visual Studio, and in case of issues update the code appropriately. Use of earlier ATL versions is nothing but unnecessary pain.

Comment: Roman R the whole point is that I can't afford a license for the version of Visual Studio that ships with ATL. Why should code written for ATL 7 not be compiled against ATL 7 or is it more about the newer compiler coupled with the older ATL? Would the code written using ATL 7 probably work ok if compiled against ATL 8? Also, I have figured out what was wrong and have come up against a new and even more intriguing problem. Question updated accordingly

Comment: The problem is that you are using WDK as a source of "free ATL", and ATL there is incomplete. Quote from WDK: "ATL is included in the WDK as a convenience for driver developers who need to create Windows applets for their drivers. ATL should not be used for software development beyond this scope." If the original ATL-based code was using VS 2003 ATL, I suppose the only ATL you can compile this code against is that included onto commercial Visual Studio.

Comment: Well that makes sense, but I still don't understand how Visual Studio Express, using the same headers and libs, is able to compile it fine and from the Visual Studio command prompt using MSBuild or nmake it fails

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using the full DevStudio IDE.  I had done exactly as you (copied Win32 settings to thex64 target platform) I Configuration Manager but kept getting that same annoying message.  I fixed it by NOT using the WinSDK v7.1 toolchain which is selectable in the project's property pages: specifically, within the "Configuration Properties" node, "General" items.  The property is called "Platform Toolset" (again, all this is within the IDE) and I changed my selection in the dropdown from Windows7.1SDK to v100.  The latter purports to utilize the DevStudio-only tools and utilities for building just about everything (e.g. HTML Help Compiler is still external).  I have a theory that if you download the latest and greatest ATL found in the [Windows Driver Kit SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800) from Microsoft.
   I hope that tidbit may be useful in steering you in the right direction.  Good luck!
S. Sean Stagner

Answer (score -1):

Create a batch fiel with the following script, then run it:

```
pause
setx DevEnvDir %%VSINSTALLDIR%%\Common7\IDE\
setx Framework35Version v3.5
setx FrameworkDir C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\
setx FrameworkVersion v4.0.30319
setx LIBPATH %%FrameworkDir%%%%FrameworkVersion%%;%%FrameworkDir%%%%Framework35Version%%
setx PATH ""
setx PATH "%%DevEnvDir%%;%%VSINSTALLDIR%%\VC\Bin;%%VSINSTALLDIR%%\Common7\Tools;%%FrameworkDir%%%%FrameworkVersion%%;%%FrameworkDir%%%%Framework35Version%%;%%VSINSTALLDIR%%\VC\VCPackages;%%PATH%%"
setx VC_PROJECT_ENGINE_NOT_USING_REGISTRY_FOR_INIT 1
setx VCINSTALLDIR %%VSINSTALLDIR%%\Bin\
setx VS100COMNTOOLS ""
setx VSINSTALLDIR "D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0"
```

Comment: This is irrelevant. The question assumes no Visual Studio installed.